# How to find all identical tables by content in PostgreSQL database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a huge PostgreSQL database and it could have several tables with same content (*same ordering*), but the names could be different. The table column names is the same. Tables with identical content could be created during updates by running new queries. Database contains about 600 tables.

I want to ask **is there any way to automatically find out the names of tables which has identical content**?

Searching by table schema does not fit there, because all of tables have the same table schema. I am using PostgreSQL 10.
I was searching for the solution long time and still no result. Maybe someone have tried something similar.

Comment: How many tables are you talking about?  Do you know the table names and column names in advance?  Does this have to complete in a single statement?  Will this be a one-off activity, or a repeated activity?  Why are there "many" differently named tables with the same structure and matching content?  The more information you can add the better; at present this is a very broad question to which you're unlikely to get a specific or useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can copy every table to csvs, no header, same delimiter. csv files with same size (or hash) will tell you exact content despite table/column names...

let say I have those two tables:

```
o=# create table t1 (i int, t text);
CREATE TABLE
o=# insert into t1 select g,chr(g) from generate_series(1,999) g;
INSERT 0 999
o=# create table t2 (e int, p text);
CREATE TABLE
o=# insert into t2 select * from t1;
INSERT 0 999
```

so I do:

```
do $$
declare _r record;
begin
 for _r in (select relname::regclass from pg_class where relname like 't%' and relkind = 'r') loop
   execute format($f$copy %I to '/tmp/%I'$f$,_r.relname, _r.relname);
 end loop;
end;
$$;
```

and I check:

```
-bash-4.2$ for i in $(ls -1 /tmp/t*); do echo "$(cat $i | md5sum) $i" ; done
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  - /tmp/t
44d8faf7b3b51a5db5f39d438dd26a60  - /tmp/t1
44d8faf7b3b51a5db5f39d438dd26a60  - /tmp/t2
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  - /tmp/t3
c5113ddc78b11ff5f9a302c539ed54e2  - /tmp/t5
26ab0db90d72e28ad0ba1e22ee510510  - /tmp/ta
08b766f7b8e96abf07a9a92d92f98c01  - /tmp/tb
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  - /tmp/tb1
b026324c6904b2a9cb4b88d6d61c81d1  - /tmp/tb2
cf8685bf8567bbc2b07a825258f58b87  - /tmp/test
ceb91e258711d9f5bd05b97df2ed1626  - /tmp/testtable
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  - /tmp/tt
```

for me t1 and t2 are same (loo above) and tb1 with tb2 (surprisingly)

Comment: Different factors could mean that the same data is stored in the tables but in a different order, yielding a different hash result for the resulting files.

Comment: surely. my solution only fits different table names and column names. which I though was the case after reading OP

Comment: Does this method will create new 600 tables?

Comment: no - it will copy table content to csv files. I create tables only to demonstrate how it works

Comment: Never did that before. Just execute this query in SQL query tool?

Comment: it will create files on server - not client. so yes - after running it in query tool, ssh to server and check md5 sums on generated files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164183/discussion-between-ejusius-and-vao-tsun).

Comment: As I understand the csv creating query is SQL type. But Query tool gives me an error on 'o=#' or 'record'. I think I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @EJusius updated the answer `o=#` is a prompt - not part of statement

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea.

Perform a check if the hash value of the Nth row of each table is the same.

then for the tables found, do the same check for a number of different random rows.

first check if the last id matches.

Comment: I am not gonna check my all 600 tables one by one. Sorry, that is not good solution.

Comment: see here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4721/postgresql-using-schema-and-table-names-from-other-tables

Comment: I think that is way different functions. Because now I should create functions for all tables to compare them.